# Setting CORS in Azure storage account from Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-storage-account

I have written some Terraform code to create an Azure storage account. Here is the code:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "i_ten_prov_storage" {
  name                     = "${var.storage_account_name}"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.i_resource_group.name}"
  location                 = "${var.location}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"

/*  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = "${var.allowed_headers}"
    allowed_methods = "${var.allowed_methods}"
    allowed_origins = "${var.allowed_origins}"
    exposed_headers = "${var.exposed_headers}"
    max_age_in_seconds = "${var.max_age_in_seconds}"
  }*/
  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["*"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
    exposed_headers = ["*"]
    max_age_in_seconds = ["*"]
  }
  tags = "${local.tags}"
}
```

I am following this documentation which says that CORS is allowed in Terraform for azure storage account:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html#allowed_headers

But I am getting the following error when I am running `terraform apply`:

```
Error: azurerm_storage_account.idl_tenant_provisioning_storage: : invalid or unknown key: cors_rule
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am using Terraform 0.11.11.

From the azure portal I can see that cors can be applied seperatly for all kind of storage

[image: Screenshot from azure portal]

and I want to apply for all kind of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cors_rule has to be inside the **blob_properties** block.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "strgacc" {
  name                     = "strgacc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
  blob_properties{
    cors_rule{
        allowed_headers = ["*"]
        allowed_methods = ["GET","HEAD","POST","PUT"]
        allowed_origins = ["https://example.com"]
        exposed_headers = ["*"]
        max_age_in_seconds = 3600
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if we want one more cors_rule with just PUT and options..?

Answer (score 2):

I think the possible solution is that executes the Azure CLI command inside the Terraform.

I find the CLI command [`az storage cors add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/cors?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-cors-add) can add the cors rule to all the service if you set the parameter `--services` with value `bfqt`. Then you can use the Terraform `null_resource` to execute the command. The example code would like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "az storage cors add --methods GET POST PUT --origins '*' --services bqft --account-name xxx"       
    }
}
```

You can more parameters as you need inside the CLI command. PowerShell command [`Set-AzStorageCORSRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstoragecorsrule?view=azps-3.3.0), but the CLI command is more convenient and suitable.

Answer (score 2):

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  name                      = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name       = data.terraform_remote_state.rg.outputs.rg_name
  location                  = data.terraform_remote_state.rg.outputs.rg_location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"

  allow_blob_public_access  = true

  blob_properties {
    cors_rule {
      allowed_headers = ["*"]
      allowed_methods = ["GET","HEAD","OPTIONS","PUT"]
      allowed_origins = ["https://google.ga", "http://localhost:4200"]
      exposed_headers = ["*"]
      max_age_in_seconds = 200
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "QA"
    Team        = "Yes"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't clear here but the `cors_rule` block should be nested under a `queue_properties` block as mentioned further down in [the documentation for the resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html):

> A `queue_properties` block supports the following:
>
> - `cors_rule` - (Optional) A `cors_rule` block as defined below.
> - `logging` - (Optional) A `logging` block as defined below.
> - `minute_metrics` - (Optional) A `minute_metrics` block as defined below.
> - `hour_metrics` - (Optional) A `hour_metrics` block as defined below.

You can also see this in [the schema for the resource in the source code](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/7f08a578b34fa9ad49c9cc02e9a6c15920a4b273/azurerm/internal/services/storage/resource_arm_storage_account.go#L309):

```golang
// ...
            "queue_properties": {
                Type:     schema.TypeList,
                Optional: true,
                Computed: true,
                MaxItems: 1,
                Elem: &schema.Resource{
                    Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                        "cors_rule": {
                            // ...
```

Comment: I see that it is applicable for queue only, how can I apply for all kind of objects